# How to show model attribute in JSP after using ajax?

Tags: ajax, spring, jsp, post, model

I have a problem. I pass `index` value from JSP to controller successfully with ajax. When I click 'pass' button, the 'index' value is increasing and it passes to controller successfully with ajax. According to this index, I add list[index] to model.(with `model.addAttribute`) Although I have used `${nextWord}` in the JSP, I cannot see this value in the view. How can I fix it? Thanks for your answer.

Controller

```
private List<Map<String, Object>> list;

@RequestMapping(value="/practice/{category}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String practicePageStart(@PathVariable("category") String category, 
                                ModelMap model, HttpSession session){
    // return 10 value from DB. Example;
    // [{idWord=1},{word='exampleWord'},{meaning='turkishMeaning'},{type='NOUN'}]
    list = wordService.getRandomWords(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("wordCount"))));
    model.addAttribute("wordList", list);

    return "practiceCategory";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/practice/{category}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String practicePagePost(@PathVariable("category") String category, 
            @RequestParam("index") int index, ModelMap model, HttpSession session){

    model.addAttribute("nextWord", list.get(index).get("word"));

    return "practiceCategory";
}
```

JSP

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {                        
        $('#pass').click(function(event) {
            var inputIndex = $('#index').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/practice/${category}",
                async: false,
                data: { index: inputIndex }
                complete: function(){   
                    alert("${nextWord}");
                    $('#label').text("${nextWord}");
                }
            });
            document.getElementById("index").value = (parseInt(document.getElementById("index").value) + 1).toString();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you get in alert?

Comment: I cannot get anything.

Comment: Try returning the Object from your controller (like `return list.get(index).get("word")`)instead of the JSP name if you are not using it anywhere else.

Comment: What is 'practiceCategory'? Is it another JSP file?

Comment: No. This is the above JSP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller method to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/practice/{category}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody 
public String practicePagePost(@PathVariable("category") String category, 
            @RequestParam("index") int index, ModelMap model, HttpSession session){

    return list.get(index).get("word");
}
```

And your ajax to this:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/practice/${category}",
                async: false,
                data: { index: inputIndex }
                success: function(data){   
                    alert(data);
                    $('#label').text(data);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Excellent. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use @ResponseBody and return the object rather then returning a ViewResolver.

Returning a ViewResolver will resolve the view and send the html content while doing an Ajax call. Hence, it is not recommended if u need only value.

@ResponseBody example

```
public @ResponseBody Integer retriveValue(-,-,-){
 return Integer.valueOf(5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I want to return a list value.(list[index]) I guess you understand that I want to return 'index'. But it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you mix different:
(1) rendring phase (servlet container - background - java) vs.
(2) running in browser (js, no request attribute existing here).

You need one another jsp file just for rendering the data. Or you return it as json in `practicePagePost` method.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/practice/{category}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String practicePagePost(@PathVariable("category") String category, 
            @RequestParam("index") int index, ModelMap model, HttpSession session){

    return list.get(index).get("word");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I fix it. :)